# Call PHP periodically with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to build a really simple web page that all it does is update the UI every second with a random number from PHP. I understand that I need to use AJAX but not familiar with it at all and could not figure out from all the research that I have done about it how to use it to accomplish my goal.

Here is my HTML/PHP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>  
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
          setInterval( function(){
              $.get("get_num.php", function(data) { 
                  $('#data').html(data);
              });
          }, 1000); 
       });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
     <?php include_once('get_num.php') ?>
    <div id="data"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

get_num.php does nothing else but echo-ing a random number.

Any idea why this code is not updating my UI with the new number every second? Am I not using AJAX properly? What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why should it update? You are making Ajax request but not updating the UI.

Comment: I see a syntax error for one. Also, the echo'd number is in your `data` variable. But you never actually do anything with it

Comment: @Vikash , how do I update the UI with the output of the PHP?

Comment: `Why are you using PHP if all you want is a random number every second? JS can do that too.

Comment: @putvande, trying to simplify the question. This PHP is a webserver that reads data from mysql.

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging?  Put a `console.log(data)` statement in the completion callback for your Ajax call to see what it does.  Look in the browser error console to see if any errors are shown?  Look in the network tab of the browser debugger to see if the ajax call is sent and to see what the server sends back?  This is basic debugging 101 - these are all steps that should be taken before you ask a question here.  You should be posting here ONLY after you've done basic debugging yourself and then you can report the results of all your basic debugging.

Comment: @jfriend00, I am super new to this that I did not even know I can debug in this way...anyway, it is now working thanks to you all guys help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code calls the get_num.php file

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("get_num.php", function(data) {
    });
}, 1000);
```

You need to add code within the line `function (data) {}` to handle the received data of the ajax call.

This could be something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("get_num.php", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("body").html(data);
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Does 'data' contain the output of the PHP? And does this additional line suppose to display it on the UI? Sorry, a bit new and confused about this. thanks!

Comment: Yes 'data' contains the output of the PHP. And the additional line tells jQuery to change the HTML element 'body' content to the value of 'data'

Comment: Changed the script (see my edits). Running it now does not change anything :( this is my whole file...is there anything else missing?

Comment: Are you sure that the php file is returning anything? I changed the code so you can check this. Add console.log(data);.

Comment: I am getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of nulla.init @ ads.js:1(anonymous function) @ ads.js:1(anonymous function) @ ads.js:1

Comment: Does this tell you anything?

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually updating your UI.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>  
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
            setInterval(function() {
                $.get("get_num.php", function(data) {
                     $('#data').html(data);
                });
            }, 1000); 
       });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
     <?php include_once('get_num.php') ?>
    <div id="data"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors you are getting? May be `get_num.php` is available in another directory.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of nulla.init @ ads.js:1(anonymous function) @ ads.js:1(anonymous function) @ ads.js:1